# Appling Jensen's inequality

Tags: inequality, derivatives

I have to prove that for every $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ $$1+\sqrt[3]{e^{2a}}\sqrt[5]{e^b}\sqrt[15]{e^{2c}}\le \sqrt[3]{(1+e^a)^2}\sqrt[5]{(1+e^b)}\sqrt[15]{(1+e^c)^2}.$$

We can prove that  $$\sqrt[3]{e^{2a}}\sqrt[5]{e^b}\sqrt[15]{e^{2c}}\le \sqrt[3]{(1+e^a)^2}\sqrt[5]{(1+e^b)}\sqrt[15]{(1+e^c)^2}$$ by appling $\ln$ function to both sides of inequality but how to prove the original one?

Comment: If that's what you're getting, then the problem seems to be wrong.

Comment: @JackLam Do you have any counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weighted Jensen and convexity of $x \mapsto \log(1+e^x) \implies$ 
$$\frac23\log(1+e^a)+\frac15\log(1+e^b)+\frac2{15}\log(1+e^c) \ge \log(1 + e^{\frac23a+\frac15b+\frac2{15}c})$$
with equality iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: As good as it gets.......